# Loading .bmp (Bitmap) and .tiff file in Flash 10 using a Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

I am developing a Image uploader using Flash 10. 
I am using `FileReference` object to browse images and Loader to show the image:

Sample code:

```
var tempFileRef:FileReference = FileReference(ev.target);
var oLoader:Loader = new Loader();
oLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoad);
oLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
oLoader.loadBytes(tempFileRef.data);
```

It works fine with **.jpg** and **.gif** files but when I browse .bmp or .tiff file, I am getting the error:

```
Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.
```

Is there a way to load and display browsed .bmp images from desktop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

BMPDecoder class from Spark lib:
http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/BMPDecoder/src/com/voidelement/images/BMPDecoder.as

Example of the usage: http://hi.baidu.com/leyhui/blog/item/d12be8b116ec915308230298.html

Regarding TIFFDecoder, it is still work in progress, but very promising one:

http://code.google.com/p/windowsbitmapdencoder/

Answer (score 1):

No.  Flash does not support .bmp and .tiff files.

[Adobe Help Docs](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000242.html)

"The bitmap image formats supported by Adobe Flash Player are GIF, JPG, and PNG."