# How do you load a bmp file from external local files?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bmp, image-load

In AS3 adobe Flash :
How do you load a ***bmp*** (**not jpg or png**) files from external local files (example: my_application_path/mybmpfiles/hello.bmp), as long as I tried it's always failed, but not error for jpg files (using loader class) ?

The error said : *Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type. URL: file:///D|/..bla-bla-bla...hello.bmp*
(loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR.ioErrorHandler)

I'm using bmp file that i got from some website or I try to made it with my microsoft paint and save it as bmp file. Even if I copy from Windows files (C:\WINDOWS\Zapotec.bmp).

Is it adobe Flash cannot loading image from bmp extension files?

Comment: try BMPDecoder and example from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106195/loading-bmp-and-tiff-file-in-flash-10-using-loader, consider this question as duplicate

Comment: thks for reply, i need to test it first.